# Creating numpy ndarray gives error buffer is too small for requested array - but it isn't

Tags: python, windows, numpy

- <sub>[Searched for duplicates but couldn't find any referring to this simple issue on Windows, so that's a self-answer]</sub>

I'm trying to create a simple 1D numpy `ndarray`, but gets an error:

```py
>>> np.ndarray(shape=(3,), buffer=np.array([1,2,3]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

Why do I get an error? the `shape` corresponds to the passed `buffer`, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

This error is observed on Windows due to the default size of integers. This is explained by one of numpy developers [on this Github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6616#issuecomment-153142056):

> [T]he problem is just that on windows the default integer type is
> always 32 bits, so you're trying to put an array of two 64 bit items into a
> buffer that's only big enough for two 32 bit items.

To elaborate a bit:

- numpy's `ndarray` default type is float (see on [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.htm), look for the word "default"), which has 64 bits.
- The buffer created on the OP code snippet doesn't pass a `dtype` argument, hence the default type is assumed, i.e. a float.
- However, the passed `buffer` is an array of integers. On windows, an integer is 32 bit (run `np.array([1,2,3]).dtype` to see it).
- As a result, an error is issued saying the buffer is too small (i.e. numpy can't create array of floats out of the too small array of integers).

To fix, there are 2 alternatives: either specify `dtype`, or make the buffer items floats:

```py
>>> np.ndarray(shape=(3,), buffer=np.array([1,2,3]), dtype=np.int32)
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.ndarray(shape=(3,), buffer=np.array([1.,2.,3.]))
array([1., 2., 3.])
```